# A priori e a posteriori

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões, escrita, linguagem

Olá, estou com dificuldades para entender as expressões latinas *"a priori"* e *"a posteriori"*, mesmo após consultar vários dicionários na internet. Se alguém puder me ajudar a esclarecer de forma mais **simples**, ficarei muito agradecido.

Comment: O Priberam diz assim: a priori
a priori
|à prióri|

locução
1. Sem ter em conta os precedentes ou a experiência.

2. Por hipótese ou por dedução. //O que você não entende nessa definição?

Comment: O Michaelis também têm uma boa definição.

Comment: Você poderia fornecer alguns exemplos dessas duas expressões? Acredito que isso me ajudaria a compreender melhor.

Answer (score 2):

No **Dicionário Priberam**

**a priori**

> locução
>
> 1. Sem ter em conta os precedentes ou a experiência.
> 2. Por hipótese ou por dedução.

Exemplos inventados por mim.

1. **A priori**, não tenho nada contra contratar esse moço para o serviço.
2. **A priori**, esse candidato parece mas inteligente que o outro.
3. **A priori**, os estudos neste campo foram encaminados diretamente ao ministério.
4. **A priori**, acho que o criminoso saiu pelo jardim e pulou o muro.

Oxalá esclareça os dois sentidos.

**a posteriori**

locução

1. Pelas razões que vêm depois; pelas conseqüências do efeito à causa.
2. Tendo em conta os precedentes ou a experiência (ex.: **método a posteriori**).

Meus exemplos:

1. O plano económico se organizou com muita rapidez e **a posteriori** [pelas conseqüências do efeito à causa]
2. Além disso, ela delineia o perfil anual da revista e buscam no espaço do editorial *organizar a posteriori seus textos*, especialmente em relação a três das quatro categorias citadas anteriormente: linha de pesquisa, abordagem metodológica e país de origem dos autores.
   [ou seja: depois de seram escritos e não antes]
   [A Educação Superior em tempos de pandemia: entre docentes e estudantes](https://periodicos.sbu.unicamp.br/ojs/index.php/riesup/article/view/8673571?articlesBySameAuthorPage=3)
3. O processo experimental da metodologia da engenharia didática é
   constituído por quatro fases: análises prévias; concepção e análise a priori [sem levar em conta os precedentes]; experimentação, análise a posteriori [dos efeitos à causa] e validação.
   [engenharia didática](https://eer.emnuvens.com.br)

[dicionario.priberam.org/a%20priori.](https://dicionario.priberam.org/a%20priori.)

[Vou revisar mas tarde. Preciso sair de casa  1/25/2024]

Answer (score 0):

A [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9935/2764) de Lambie já dá definições e exemplos. Eu sumarizaria os significados dessas expressões da seguinte forma:

- *a priori* é seu ponto de partida, numa análise ou discussão, por exemplo;
- *a posteriori* é o que se pode concluir depois do acontecido.

Por exemplo: **A priori**, uma confissão é uma forte evidência de culpa num caso criminal, mas se as diligências revelam que o suspeito havia sido coagido a confessar, então, **a posteriori**, esta confissão pode ser desconsiderada pelo juiz encarregado do processo.